# Remove status bar and keep resize icon in tinymce 4

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to remove the status bar and keep the resize icon in tinymce just like a normal text area resizer. Any idea ?

Answer (score 5):

#### [elementpath](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#elementpath)

This option allows you to disable the element path within the status bar at the bottom of the editor.

**Type:**

`Boolean`

**Default Value:**

`true`

**Possible Values:**

`true`, `false`

[Example](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#exampleusingelementpath)

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea',// change this value according to your HTML
    elementpath:false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE does not support what you are trying to do via configuration.  The resize handle is only visible via the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do it via component settings. But you can try and change css:

```
your-tiny-mce-textarea .mce-path.mce-flow-layout-item {
    display: none !important;
}
```

UPD: This one seems more pretty:

```
your-tiny-mce-textarea.mce-statusbar {
    border: 0 !important;
}
your-tiny-mce-textarea.mce-path {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone in future, you can remove the entire status bar with the following option

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  statusbar: false
});
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#statusbar